# How can yeast be kosher lǝPesach?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover

I was once reading the ingredients on a pack of [Bissli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bissli) (with a Pesach hashgacha) and saw that it contained yeast. How can this be?

Comment: Bissli has a Wikipedia page!?!? +1

Comment: @Shokhet, I would have used Osem's page, but I couldn't find it. PS. many treif snacks have Wiki pages.

Comment: Aside from the question of maris ayin for its similarity to chametz bissli (though for some reason this seldom seems to be a concern of the kashrus industry).

Answer (score 7):

Yeast is not Chametz.

Chametz is defined as the five grains rising.

Yeast, on the other hand, is made from [potato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeast#Nutrition_and_growth):

> In general, yeasts are grown in the laboratory on solid growth media or in liquid broths. Common media used for the cultivation of yeasts include potato dextrose agar or potato dextrose broth, Wallerstein Laboratories nutrient agar, yeast peptone dextrose agar, and yeast mould agar or broth.

Comment: What about Se'or?

Comment: @DoubleAA Se'or is your sourdough starter. It still contains flour and water.

Comment: You'll also see "torula yeast" in some ingredients. Papermakers have "wood soup" in need of disposal, and the torula yeast eat the nutrients in that. Win for the papermakers, win for the yeastmakers, win for kashrus because pine is kosher l'pesach, pareve, lamehadrin!

Comment: @Shalom but perhaps that should be explicated in the answer...

Comment: You can also have grape yeast for winemaking.

Comment: Even if yeast not raised on wheat isn't se'or, I would think there would still be a concern with adding it to matzo meal if it would trigger fermentation/chimutz...?

Comment: @loewian You are right. However, since it won't trigger chimutz, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yeast are single celled microorganisms that are classified as Fungi and can be found on everything. There are many sources of yeast which do not come in contact with chometz and therefore are not a concern for pesach such as grapes and other fruits and vegetables.

Answer (score -1):

Leaven is a chemical interaction between any of the 5 grains wheat, spelt, oats, barley, or rye and yeast.  (And, technically, what we today call oats isn't the original oat, not "shibolet se-orah" as it was back then.  It actually doesn't ferment like the other 4, so we likely lost a species along the way an substituted.)  Yeast alone is not leaven, as wheat and water baked quickly enough is not leaven, as the yeast in the air hasn't enough time to leaven it, and no yeast is otherwise added.

Comment: But what about Se'or.

Comment: I think you mean _shibbolet shu'al_, and whether that means oats is an ongoing dispute.