# How is wine; a fermented beverage, permitted on Passover?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, passover, grapes-wine, four-cups-wine

As any of you who have made wine (or other alcoholic drinks) know, yeast is essential in the fermentation of alcoholic beverage. So how can we drink wine on Pesach, more than this it's an essential part of the seder? The presence of fermented yeast is surely chametz, something we can't even have in our possession on Pesach.

Comment: Why do you think it would be a problem? Consider clarifying.

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45865/759  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81716/759

Comment: all alcohol is fermented. why just ask about wine?

Comment: "The presence of fermented yeast is surely chametz" This is simply not true. Why do you assert it so confidently?

Comment: chametz is something made from one of the 5 grains which has fermented. *Not* anything that is fermented.

Answer (score 2):

So far 2 answers have been offered.

[This site](http://www.chabad.org/library/howto/wizard_cdo/aid/1755/jewish/1-What-Is-Chametz.htm) says:

> Chametz is "leaven" -- any food that's made of grain and water that
>   have been allowed to ferment and "rise."

So:

1) the yeast in liquid is not considered chametz as it is not a baked, flour/water combination

2) yeast is similar to bacteria and is present in unfermented grapes so no grainlike products are required

Comment: Tried to improve answer; roll it back if you don't like it.